# Device or resource busy error when pendrive is connected

Tags: android, kernel, usb, android-source

I am working with AOSP-Q. When i connect the pendrive to my android device, i am getting prints like :

```
[ 2955.285052] read strings
[ 2955.288151] init: processing action (sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1) from (init.usb.configfs.rc:26)
[ 2955.303196] init: Command 'write /config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC ${sys.usb.controller}' action=sys.usb.config=adb && sys.usb.configfs=1 && sys.usb.ffs.ready=1 (init.usb.configfs.rc:29) took 0ms and failed: Unable to write to file '/config/usb_gadget/g1/UDC': Unable to write file contents: Device or resource busy
```

I somewhere found that enabling the **CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_F_FS** config in the kernel causes that prints, so i disabled that config. Now i am not getting that prints when i connect pendrive but **ADB over USB** is not working for me. can anyone help me to get rid of that prints without effecting the **ADB over USB** functionality.